# Find bijection between two sets of multisets/sequences

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find a bijection $f$ between the sets of multisets with k types.

$A_k$ = {$(a_1,...,a_k) : a_i = c_i \times i,\ \exists\ c_i \in \mathbb{N}$}

and $B_k$ = {$(b_1,...,b_k) : b_i \geq b_j,\ \forall i<j \in \mathbb{N}$}

such that $a_1+...+a_k=b_1+...+b_k$ for all $f((a_1,...,a_k))=(b_1,...,b_k)$

Since we don't care about the actual content of the multisets, we can also just view them as sequences, where the number of types in the multiset is the length of the sequence, and number of elements of $i_{th}$ type is the value of $i_{th}$ term of the sequence.

My attempt:

I noticed that this problem can be viewed as trying to express a number as a sum of other numbers in two different ways. We can view $c_i$ as denoting how often $i$ appears in the output multiset. So 2,2,0,0 in $A_4$ says that 1 appears twice (since $c_1=2$) and 2 appears once (since $c_2=1$), and the output should be 2,1,1,0 in $B_4$.

The above method doesn't work if the size of the multiset (the sum of all numbers) exceeds the number of types of that multiset. For example, 5,0,0 has to be mapped to 1,1,1,1,1 in this way, but 5,0,0 is in $A_3$ while 1,1,1,1,1 is in $B_5$.

I'm wondering if there's a more general solution to this.

Comment: @Karl They can have different values for $c_i$, so 2,2,0,0 is $(1\times 2,2\times 1,3\times 0,4\times 0)$, where $c_1 = 2, c_2 = 1, c_3 = c_4 = 0$

Comment: You seem to be using the words "multiset" and "type" in unusual ways. Could you clarify your definitions with some examples? It looks to me like $A_k$ is the set of tuples of length $k$ of integers such that the $i$th component is divisible by $i$, and $B_k$ is the set of non-increasing tuples (of nonnegative integers?) of length $k$. Is that right?

Comment: I understand your attempt now. Another problem will be ensuring that $f$ is surjective. Maybe we should start with the case $k=2$.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. For $k=2$, we can let $f((c_1,2c_2))=(c_1+c_2,c_2)$. This approach can be generalized to larger $k$.

Comment: @Karl I know this is not how these words are typically used, but that's how they are used in the context of this question, so to clarify things I also explained that they can just be viewed as sequences. Your interpretation is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Karl gave a suggestion in the comments and I think it works.

The generalization to that is just $b_i=c_i+c_{i+1}+...+c_k$

It's injective since: suppose there are two different multisets from $A_k$ that maps to the same multiset in $B_k$, so $f((a_{1_1},...,a_{k_1}))=(b_{1_1},...,b_{k_1})=(b_{1_2},...,b_{k_2})=f((a_{1_2},...,a_{k_2}))$, and that $b_{i_1} = b_{i_2} = c_{i_1}+...+c_{k_1} = c_{i_2}+...+c_{k_2}$ for all natural numbers $i\leq k$. Let the smallest index between $i$ and $k$ in which the two multisets from $A_k$ differ be $x$, so $i \leq x \leq j$ and $c_{x_1} \neq c_{x_2}$. Then $b_{(x+1)_1} \neq b_{(x+1)_2}$ since $b_{x_1} = b_{x_2}$ but $c_{x_1} \neq c_{x_2}$. Then we have a contradiction, so it's injective.

It's also surjective since any member of $B_k$ has the property that $b_1=...=b_{change_1} > b_{change_1+1}=...=b_{change_2}>...>...=b_{change_n}$, where $change_i$ denotes that the next element changes value, and the last $change_i$ denotes the end. Just choose all the $c_i$ between each changepoints to be 0, and choose $c_{change_i} = b_{change_1} - b_{change_1+1}$, then any element from $B_k$ can be constructed